# Whats wrong with this program in C? It terminates. I am having difficulty in understanding read input string in pointer of pointers

Tags: c, string, pointers, scanf

When I gave input as 1 any string it terminates. Please help me understand the working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  int t,j,i;
  scanf("%d",&t);
  char *inp[t];
  char *tmp;
  for(i=0;i<t;i++)
  {
    scanf("%s",tmp);
    printf("0");
    strcpy(inp[i],tmp);
    printf("%s",inp[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Formatting/indentation:(

Comment: 'scanf("%s",tmp);' tmp is uninitialized.

Comment: In `scanf("%s",tmp);` the variable `tmp` has no memory allocated. it is an unitialised pointer, leading to *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: ... and neither have the elements of `char *inp[t];` so `strcpy(inp[i],tmp);` will cause an explosion in the population of frogs. Croak.

Comment: The strcpy() and printf() don't make much sense.  Did you mean to use a 2D array or an array of pointers to char arrays?

Comment: I just wants to know the error in program(asked in examination), there is no specific purpose of the program. I am weak in c so i cant point out error.
Thanks all for the answer.

Answer (score 4):

`scanf("%s",tmp)` writes to the memory pointed by `tmp`, but you never initialized `tmp` to point to writable memory.

Similarly, `strcpy(inp[i],tmp)` writes to the memory pointed by `inp[i]`, but you never initialized `inp[i]` to point to writable memory.

You probably want this:

```
int main() {
  int t,i;
  scanf("%d",&t);
  char *inp[t];                         // array of t pointers to char
  char tmp[100];                        // array of 100 chars

  for(i=0;i<t;i++)
  {
    scanf("%s",tmp);
    inp[i] = malloc(strlen(tmp) + 1);   // allocate space for new string
                                        // (+1 for the NUL terminator)
    strcpy(inp[i],tmp);                 // copy the string in tmp to
                                        // the newly allocated space
  }

  // print all strings
  for(i=0;i<t;i++)
  {
    printf("%s\n",inp[i]);
  }

  for(i=0;i<t;i++)
  {
    free(inp[i]));   // free previously allocated memory
                     // (not really necessary here, just to be perfect)
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: LOL! .................

Comment: @MartinJames anyway now everything is correct

Comment: @ikegami he probably wants the user to type a number (t), then he wants the user to type t strings and the pointers to eachof the strings should be stored in the `inp`array.

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted.

Comment: t :D P.S. Missed free() after using malloc() : )

Comment: @SunDro OK, but for this kind of toy programs it's not really important.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I know but it turned into the habit :/

Comment: Please stop editing the code.  If you keep that up, 'n' wil be back.  I've  upvoted it already..

Comment: Tip: `inp[i] = malloc(strlen(tmp) + 1); strcpy(inp[i],tmp);` can be reduced to `inp[i] = strdup(tmp);`

Comment: I just wants to know the error in program(asked in examination), there is no specific purpose of the program. I am weak in c so i cant point out error.
Thanks all for the answer.